# How do I use cpanminus with a local CPAN::Mini?

Tags: perl, cpan, minicpan

I've created my own local copy of CPAN with [minicpan](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/CPAN-Mini-1.111007/bin/minicpan) and managed to reconfigure cpan to use it - Fantastic!

..but how would I go about using it with [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.5004/lib/App/cpanminus.pm)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be possible using [`--mirror-only`](https://metacpan.org/module/cpanm#mirror-only)option.

For example:

```
cpanm --mirror ~/minicpan --mirror-only
```

Comment: Is there not a config I can put these options in, so that it always uses them?

Comment: `alias minicpanm='cpanm --mirror ~/minicpan --mirror-only'` as described on cpanm help page. You just need to create shell alias

Comment: @Hugh As is mentioned in `cpanm --help` you can also specify options in the `PERL_CPANM_OPT` environment variable. e.g. to use the mirror as described above by default: `export PERL_CPANM_OPT="--mirror ~/minicpan --mirror-only"`