# Unable to install perl modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to install a `perl` module on a machine which doesn't have internet access.
I am trying with PPM in order to install the `perl` modules, and I have followed all steps which are mentioned in the following link over
[here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/01/11/painless-ppm.html).

But still I am unable to install a `perl` module,and it is not giving any errors.

Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You said you dont have internet on that machine. Then try `minicpan`. [take a look here](http://p3rl.org/minicpan)

Comment: with the ppm files are not updating, but the version is updating. i am unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller can you please tell me how to install minicpan.

Comment: So when you work on windows, thats a bit more tricky. The `make` is called `dmake` under windows. Take a look [here](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/dmake/)

Comment: ya for windows its dmake but to install dmake we need internet connection to install dmake module

Comment: You can set mirrors on activeperl as well. Just use the minicpan as mirror and install it then.

Answer (score 0):

Two(5) :) step solution:

1. Install `minicpan` see the link in the Paulchenkiller's comment or [here is](http://perlbuzz.com/mechanix/2008/01/make-your-own-mini-cpan.html) about it.
2. make your own local cpan mirror
3. put the minicpan-mirror into usb hdd or usb stick
4. install `cpanm` into your machine (or configure `cpan` for using the mirror)
5. use the `cpanm --mirror /path/to/minicpan --mirror-only` command to install modules as asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8139088/632407)

Comment: **A PPM comes along with Activestate perl,Make and install happens using already built in perl modules..so we felt creating local repository and installing modules would be the best solution.

 And with MiniCpan i need namke/gmake to be installed first to build MiniCPAN...isn't it?

 We are working on windows machine..where in getting namke is becoming difficult with out a license.**

Comment: @SureshJaladi huh - sorry, I knows nothing about Activestate perl nor about windows ;(. Maybe Strawberry perl on windows has all needed things to make an working perl installation. (off topic: do you think than **BOLD** comment is more helpful?) ;)